# assertRaises BadRequest isn't working

Tags: django, tastypie, restful-architecture, django-testing

I'm using django tastypie to create my restful endpoints. So it's time to make the login endpoint, (it is not complete yet).

**accounts/api/resources.py**

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['post']
        serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])

    def prepend_urls(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return [
            url(r'^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login/$' % self._meta.resource_name,
                self.wrap_view('dispatch_login'), name='api_dispatch_login')
        ]

    def dispatch_login(self, request, **kwargs):
        self.method_check(request, allowed=['post'])

        data = self._meta.serializer.from_json(request.body)  # This raises the exception.

        return self.create_response(request, {}, status=200)
```

**accounts/tests.py**

```
class UserApiTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.uri = reverse('api_dispatch_login', kwargs={'api_name': 'v1',
                           'resource_name': 'user'})

    def test_login_user_credentials_sent_in_body_request(self):
        with self.assertRaises(BadRequest):
            self.client.post(self.uri, content_type='application/json')
```

By consuming the web service using the terminal emulator and curl, I can see the exception is raised.

```
$ curl localhost:8000/api/v1/user/login/ --request POST
{"error": "Request is not valid JSON."}
```

But while running the tests, the assertion just fail.

```
FAIL: test_login_user_credentials_sent_in_body_request (accounts.tests.UserApiTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/slackmart/code/superproject/accounts/tests.py", line 29, in test_login_user_credentials_sent_in_body_request
    self.client.post(self.uri, content_type='application/json')
AssertionError: BadRequest not raised
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/django-tastypie/django-tastypie/blob/master/docs/release_notes/dev.rst

> Added UnsupportedSerializationFormat and
>   UnsupportedDeserializationFormat exceptions, which are caught and
>   result in HttpNotAcceptable (406 status) and HttpUnsupportedMediaType
>   (415 status) responses, respectively. Previously these same types of
>   errors woud have appeared as 400 BadRequest errors.

Recent changes to Tastypie have been made to make it more HTTP compliant and error codes more specific. You'll want to look for either a 406 or 415 status code instead of a 400.